# How send XMLHttpRequest Asynchronous Post in the background?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

When the user clicks on a button, I want to take the user to another web page by changing window.location, while making a HTTP Post request in the background. The HTTP Post must be asynchronous. How can I do that?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#b1").click(function(event){


        try{

             //call function that sends HTTP POST in the background
             window.location="http://www.stackoverflow.com";

        } catch(e) {


          alert(e.message);

         }
      });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "HTTP post" exactly, an Ajax request? That request will die the moment you change the page's location. You will have to wait until the Ajax request has finished, or do it in a different window (e.g. a popup)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You can do one of those things, not both.

Comment: I want to use XMLHttpRequest to send a POST request. request.open("POST", URL, true);

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to send the AJAX call on the button click, and then switch pages after the AJAX call comes back

Comment: I don't want the AJAX POST call to interfere with the user interface. Can HTML5 worker do what I want?

Comment: You can create new window/tab, populate it's content with form submit it and change location of your current window at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open new browser window/tab that will perform asynchronous post request and auto-close after response is received and at the same time you may change location of your own window.

```
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var w = window.open('about:blank');
    w.document.write([
      '<html>',
        '<body>',
          '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>',
          '<script>',
            '$.post("http://my.site.com", "data to be sent").always(function() {',
              'window.close();',
            '})',
          '</script>',
        '</body>',
      '</html>'
    ].join(''));
    window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
  });  
});
```

Comment: What if I create a HTML5 worker that makes the post request from the main window? Would changing the location of the main window terminates the HTML5 worker thread?

Comment: I don't want the user to see the new window/tab. Is there a way to open a hidden window that will perform the asyn post request?